# KIE Workbench Integration in spring throw exception

Tags: spring, maven, drools, kie-workbench

What I want to do is to init the KieSession in Spring when the tomcat start. And The  KieSession will dynamicly change when the rules are changed and redeployed as jar in the kie-workbench.

I downloaded the kie-drools-wb-6.3.0.Final-tomcat7.war and deployed it in a linux machine.I can use the following code to test:

```
public class TestScanMaven {
public static void main(String[] args) {
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

try {
    ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId("com.test","epay-risk2",   "LATEST");


    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);


    KieScanner kieScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
    kieScanner.start(20000L);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        runRule(kieContainer);
        System.out.println("Press enter in order to run the test again....");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out
            .println("Exception thrown while constructing InputStream");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}

private static void runRule(KieContainer kieContainer) {
KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("defaultKieSession");
// go !
Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("Hello World");
message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
kSession.insert(message);
kSession.fireAllRules();
}
}
```

this code work quite well。
But when I change to use the following code in spring,It throw exception

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){

    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId("com.test","epay-risk2", "LATEST");

    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);


    kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("defaultKieSession");


    kSession.setGlobal("riskRecordService", riskRecordService);


    KieScanner kieScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
    kieScanner.start(20000L);
}
```

the Exception thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.Binder.bindListener(Lcom/google/inject/matcher/Matcher;[Lcom/google/inject/spi/ProvisionListener;)V
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule.configure(PlexusBindingModule.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:477)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:203)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:167)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:166)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:140)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.<init>(PlexusComponentProvider.java:37)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildComponentProvider(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:56)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:75)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:69)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:55)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:49)
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:36)
    at org.drools.compiler.kproject.xml.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:89)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getPomModel(AbstractKieModule.java:395)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getJarDependencies(AbstractKieModule.java:126)
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:64)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:68)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:56)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieModule(KieBuilderImpl.java:221)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.build(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:220)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.buildArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:170)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.loadArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:126)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.loadArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:121)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.loadKieModuleFromMavenRepo(KieRepositoryImpl.java:129)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:115)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:92)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:115)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:111)
    at com.test.risk.service.risk.epay.rule.impl.RiskKieServiceImpl.init(RiskKieServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
```

The settings in my maven home is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<servers>
<server>
  <id>guvnor-m2-repo</id>
  <username>drools_tomcat</username>
  <password>XXXXXX</password>
  <configuration>
    <wagonProvider>httpclient</wagonProvider>
    <httpConfiguration>
      <all>
        <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
      </all>
    </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
</server>
</servers>

<profiles>

<profile>
  <id>guvnor-m2-repo</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>guvnor-m2-repo</id>
      <name>BRMS Repository</name>
      <url>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8082/guvnor/maven2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>

</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
 <activeProfile>guvnor-m2-repo</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Comment: the answer recommened: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916936/spring-integration-with-drools>